# Delete a Primary Key Without Affecting Foreign Key Constrain to Other Table

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a record from a school table without affecting a foreign key to the department name. I tried but I got this message:

> "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`arusms`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `department_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`school_name`) REFERENCES `school` (`school_name`) ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)"

Comment: Can you please show how your database is set up?

Comment: I think it may not be possible. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: If a department is part of a school, and you delete the school, this implies that the department is gone too.  What you are asking does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that.  If you delete the school, the department will be orphaned.  That's the point of having foreign keys in the first place, to enforce referential integrity.  If you want the department to remain and to be able to do this, you will need to alter the foreign key to include ON DELETE SET NULL.  Otherwise, you will have to drop the constraint, perform the delete, and recreate the constraint.

Comment: If drop the constraint and perform the delete, then you won't be able to recreate the constraint :)

Comment: @ypercube : If you set foreign_key_checks to 0 then you can.  Actually, that would be easier than deleting it anyway.  Set foreign_key_checks to 0, delete the record, set foreign_key_checks to 1.  It's a dirty hack, but again, I don't understand the reason for wanting to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is hiding the real cause.

```
(
arusms.department, 

CONSTRAINT department_ibfk_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (school_name) 
  REFERENCES school (school_name) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

When you created the foreign key constarint, you omitted the `ON DELETE` part. MySQL used the default action for this, which is **`ON DELETE RESTRICT`**. See the MySQL docs: [`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

If you want to be able to delete schools without cascading effect to the related departments, you can either

- remove the FK constraint or
- make the column (`department.school_name`) nullable and alter the constraint to have the `ON DELETE SET NULL` action.

If you want to be able to delete schools and cascading deleting the related departments, you can

- alter the constraint to have the `ON DELETE CASCADE` action.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of having a foreign key is to keep data consistent. In your case, it means that for each `department`, there must exist a corresponding `school` record. And if you `DELETE` a school, all corresponding departments should be deleted as well, or at least their `school` reference must be `NULL`ed.

If you don't need this kind of enforcement, `DROP` the foreign key.

Alternatively, if you just want to reassign a department to another school, first do that, and only then `DELETE` the original school.